# How do add a mouse over text on selected area of an image?

Tags: html, css

I have this image and i would like to add a mouse over text on the selected area of this image.

For example if you look at this image and mouse over on the letter A, i would like to add a small description in a box. how is this be done ?

can someone please help.

thanks

Comment: What steps have you taken so far? The point of this site is to get help with existing code - not to ask for someone else's coding efforts.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this, this is why i asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution to your question. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vfM55/1/) (shows how to do it with 2 points)**

It involves a relatively positioned div with your image as the background. Then there are some absolutely positioned "Hover Points" that trigger the tooltip.

Once you get this working, you can remove the red borders and style the tooltip however you'd like.

**HTML**

```
<div id="image">
    <div class="hoverPoint" style="top:312px;left:178px;" data-content="This is a test (A)"></div>
    <div class="hoverPoint" style="top:37px;left:379px;" data-content="This is a test (C)"></div>
    <div id="tooltip"></div>    
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.hoverPoint').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#tooltip')
        .css({
            top: ($(this).position().top-30) + 'px',
            left: $(this).position().left + 'px'
         })
         .html( $(this).data('content') )
         .show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#tooltip')
        .html('')
        .hide();
});
```

**CSS**

```
#image{
    background:url(http://oi44.tinypic.com/2ur9to5.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:888px;
    height:441px;
    position:relative;
}
#tooltip{
    position:absolute;  
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #999;
    padding:4px;
    display:none;
}
.hoverPoint{
    position:absolute;
    width:47px;
    height:47px;
    border:1px solid #f00;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: this is good, just that i could not get the function to work. 
I have it like that
"<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>"
and here my script..

anything i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a link to the actual page I can look at? Otherwise, check the console for errors and let me know what they say.

Comment: i am trying it on my computer for now, but the console gives me no error

Comment: i could see the pointer, but when i mouse over nothing happens

Comment: I'm going to need to see some code. If you want to email me the HTML file, my webpage is in my profile and you can find my contact info there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45657/discussion-between-dutchie432-and-rockydude)

Answer (score 2):

How about achieving that with pure CSS, am just using CSS positioning to set the circle correctly on the edge of the triangle, and than am using `content: attr()` property, in which am calling the custom attribute declared by me which is `data-title`, so that's all, rest is self explanatory.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/64Wze/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/64Wze/1/) *(2 Dots)*

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://wilsonsch3u-01-2012.wikispaces.com/file/view/triangle.png" alt="" />
    <span data-title="This is a custom title"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

div img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

div span {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
}

span:hover:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Arial;
    width: 200px;
    top: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Note: You can also achieve this using `background-image` instead of `img`

Comment: @rockydude This is **PURE CSS** so you should expect in limits :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the :hover selector

css:

```
.divWithMessage:hover > .message {
    display: block
}
```

html:

```
<div class="divWithMessage">
    A
    <div class="message">This is a message. Use CSS to position it.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The unique way that i know to do that is a a bit cumbersome to map the point of every region.
For exampe you can imagine a rect that bound the lecter A.
If the moouse over the image is into this range of point you can append in this position a DOM element or do some stuff.

For example you can imagine this solution:

```
var zona1X = new Array(400, 438, 438, 394);
var zona1Y = new Array(305, 355, 284, 280);

var zona2X = new Array(450, 580, 580, 450);
var zona2Y = new Array(360, 500, 270, 270);

var zona3X = new Array(360, 370, 430, 400);
var zona3Y = new Array(320, 390, 360, 320);
```

then

```
$('.yourElement').mousemove(function (e) {
    var height = 545; //yourElementHeight
    var x = e.offsetX;
    var y = height - e.offsetY;
    var isHover = false;

    x += ($(e.srcElement).offset().left - $(this).offset().left);
    y += ($(this).offset().top - $(e.srcElement).offset().top);


    if (pnpoly(zona1X.length, zona1X, zona1Y, x, y) && !isHover) {
        //Do some stuff!
    }

    if (pnpoly(zona2X.length, zona2X, zona2Y, x, y) && !isHover) {
        //Do some stuff!
    }

    //etc...

    if (isHover) {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    } else {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
    }
});
```

and this is the function to interpolate the point:

```
function pnpoly(nvert, vertx, verty, testx, testy) {
    var i, j, c = false;
    for (i = 0, j = nvert - 1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
        if (((verty[i] > testy) != (verty[j] > testy)) &&
        (testx < (vertx[j] - vertx[i]) * (testy - verty[i]) / (verty[j] - verty[i]) + vertx[i])) {
            c = !c;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```